# OpalVoip Still sending OLC after Recieving Empty TCS

Tags: voip, h.323, opalvoip

Empty TCS is used for pausing and re-routing a call.
Why is OpalVoip still sending OLC requests while on HOLD. Opal v 3.12(Eridani)
[image: Wireshark dump]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the OPAL library. I would suggest to post this on their [mailinglist](http://www.opalvoip.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.MailingLists), including info how to reproduce the issue.